# Programming a Discord bot in Python- Why is it unable to set embed images?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a meme command that gets a URL from a subreddit and then sets it as an embed image. Here's my code:

```
memes = reddit.subreddit("memes")
memes_subs = []
memes_hot = memes.hot(limit = 50)

for submission in memes_hot:
  memes_subs.append(submission)


@client.command()
async def meme(ctx):
  random_sub = random.choice(memes_subs)
  name = random_sub.title
  url = random_sub.url

  em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = 0xfdcb58)
  em.set_footer(text = f"Requested by {ctx.message.author} | From r/memes")
  em.set_image(url = url)

  await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

Sometimes the embed does not have an image, or the image simply won't load. I am unsure why this happens, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What gappens when you print url = random_sub.url

Comment: Are you sure the url is valid and the client is loading the image properly?

Comment: I do not know if the URL is valid or not, it varies each time- how would I check so?

Comment: you can check with print

Comment: Yes and you can tell us what is this url

Comment: Well like I said the link is different each time, but one example is when it ended with a ".gifv" which was clearly supposed to be ".gif", is there a way to prevent bad links like that from occurring again?

Comment: gifv are mp4 file. You should use some library to convert it to a gif, or try get the first frame? Using some mp4 library

Comment: That link ending in Gifv are actually link though, so dont add the image this is a website link html

Answer (score 2):

Some Imgur URLs end in gifv because they are web pages, not direct links. To get the original GIF, you can change the link into this format: `http://i.imgur.com/12345.jpg`
Note the .jpg, not a .gif. This will give you a raw GIF file though.

For gfycat, The alternative link format `https://thumbs.gfycat.com/ElatedEvergreenGoose-size_restricted.gif` can be used

Comment: Thanks for the help! There is another link I found causing trouble though- it's a *gfycat* link, with no extension at all. How would I fix that one?

Comment: Wait, I've added something to the answer @CarterMichaelis