# In my cat command everything works but often the imgae wont load in discord

Tags: python, discord.py, reddit

```py
    @client.command(aliases=['cats'])
    async def cat(ctx):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
            async with cs.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/cats/hot.json') as r: #the link
                res = await r.json()
                embed = discord.Embed(title='There you go^^', color=0xef42f5) # the embed
                embed.set_image(url=res['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
                embed.set_footer(icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url, text = f'Requested by {ctx.author.name}')
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

`So as of now, the bot sends an embed like I want, but often the image wont load which is why I am asking this question. Did I do anything wrong and/or how can I fix it?`
And if i formatted anything wrong pls dont be mad im new here and I dont know how to format everything the right way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programming a Discord bot in Python- Why is it unable to set embed images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67286726/programming-a-discord-bot-in-python-why-is-it-unable-to-set-embed-images)

Comment: What are the image urls? Can you send an example?

Comment: thanks for helping i already managed to fix it myself

Comment: @LonelyGuy How about answering your own question so that people in the future can see how to solve a similar problem ;)

Comment: i just used an other reddit lmao